# Difference between Dovecot and Z-push

Tags: dovecot

I am trying to understand how email on a Linux system works.  From Google searches I encountered both [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) and [Z-push](http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/) in the context of push mail, and sometimes used together.

I was under the impression that IMAP is push so why would anything else be needed? Am I wrong? So if Dovecot handles IMAP then what exactly is the difference between Dovecot and Z-push and what are their purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot is an IMAP server. The IMAP protocol contains push capability, but not all clients and servers implement it. IMAP only handles email.

Z-push implements the Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync protocol. This protocol can be used to sync email, contacts, calendars and tasks. Z-push needs either an IMAP server or a dir with all mails for email sync. If Z-push is configured for IMAP it can use dovecot, so this is how they can work together.

Some devices work better with ActiveSync than with IMAP and ActiveSync can sync more data, so this is the reason for using Z-push.